# ARM Android emulator OVA or how to export AVD ARM emulator image to VirtualBox

Tags: android, android-emulator, arm, virtualbox, android-virtual-device

I was wondering if there are ARM Android emulator images for VirtualBox available as I merely found x86 images during my search.

If there's no such image, is it possible to somehow export/convert an ARM emulator image created with Android's AVD to an OVA file so I can import it to VirtualBox?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to run an ARM emulator, do you really need an x86 VM to do that inside? Can't you just run it on the host machine?

Comment: I want to be able to start both, an ARM and an x68 Android VM in my project, depending on the current chosen option since some functionalities depend on the architecture.

Comment: OK, but "start VirtualBox (with x86 Android image)" vs. "start QEMU (with ARM Android image)" doesn't seem much more difficult than "start VirtualBox with an x86 Android image" vs. "start Virtualbox with some other Linux/Windows VM which then runs QEMU with the ARM Android image inside", and means you don't need the overhead of running a _third_ OS inbetween the host machine and Android.